# SQL Cache and Joins in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me how to use SQL Cache in joins?

I know this query is wrong.

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE COLUMN1 
FROM TABLE1 WHERE CONDITION1 
UNION 
SELECT SQL_CACHE COLUMN1
FROM TABLE1 WHERE CONDITION2
```

Also please tell me how can I check if query results are coming from cache?

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming you mean union instead of join here.) Parameters like sql_cache should be used once only in the very first select, and then omitted.

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE COLUMN1 
FROM TABLE1 WHERE CONDITION1 
UNION 
SELECT COLUMN1
FROM TABLE1 WHERE CONDITION2
```

As for whether the query is coming from the MySQL query cache, I don't think there's a way dynamically. If you're doing this on an idle server I guess you can look at the query cache system variables before and after you run the query.